# Delay a click on a button for effect to happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add this effect: http://codepen.io/440design/pen/iEztk on my buttons. I've added the code, the style and everything, but the problem is that when I click on a button I don't see the effect happening because my button sends me to the desired link. So I tried with `setTimeout`, but didn't have any luck, and if I use `preventDefault()` I'll prevent the link to going where it's needed.

I tried with this

```
var ink, d, x, y;
    $(".ripplelink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).find(".ink").length === 0){
            $(this).prepend("<span class='ink'></span>");
        }

        ink = $(this).find(".ink");
        ink.removeClass("animate");

        if(!ink.height() && !ink.width()){
            d = Math.max($(this).outerWidth(), $(this).outerHeight());
            ink.css({height: d, width: d});
        }

        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ink.width()/2;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ink.height()/2;

        ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");    
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ripplelink').unbind('click');
    }, 2000);
```

But this isn't working. If I prevent default and not unbind it, I can see the ripple effect, but I need the link to work.

In essence I'd like to click the button, see the effect, and then the link would send me where I need to go.

Comment: Just do whatever you need to do (animation) and change the `location` to reflect the link right after.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.href = "YOUR link";` to switch to the side after your animation.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but `location.href` will just return return the current html of current page. I need the link to go to a location that is set in the link.

Comment: Yes, it returns the current URL, but you also can set the current URL like this: `location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";` this would open SO on its execute.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it. I just need to set the `setTimeout` on `location.href`. Thanks!